# Как сделать сдвиг по столбцу в формуле Excel с помощью VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-формулы

Пример:

в ячейке "A1" содержится формула "=A2+A4+A6"

Мне необходимо, с помощью VBA,  в ячейку B1 поместить эту формулу но с литерой "B". Есть ли способ?

Единственное что-то похожее нашел в сети:

```
With Range("A1")
.Formula = "=SUM(" & .DirectPrecedents.Offset(0,1).Address(0, 0) & ")"
End With
```

Это не совсем то, но я мог бы это приспособить, если бы работало.
Выдает ошибку о том что не найдено ни одной подходящей ячейки.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, возможно кому то пригодится.

```
Range(from_cell_address).AutoFill Destination:=Range(address_text), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

где from_cell_address - адрес ячейки содержащей формулу,

а address_text интервал необходимый для заполнения

вот как это выглядит у меня

```
Range("A1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:B1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Результатом будет ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Достаточно включить запись макроса и проделать такое размножение либо копирование руками - сразу получишь именно такой результат.

Comment: `Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = Range("A1").FormulaR1C1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test1()
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
End Sub
```

Если формат одинаков или не важен, достаточно копировать ячейку полностью:

```
Sub test(): Range("A1").Copy Range("B1"): End Sub
```